# Iterate over an ArrayList with multiple condition in Java

Tags: java, arraylist, iterator

Scenario: An Arraylist containing following DTOs.

```
MetadatRetrievalDTO[] dto  = new MetadatRetrievalDTO[16];

dto[0] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[0].setArticleId(11);
dto[0].setBaseId("SB11");
dto[0].setMetadataName("TYPE");
dto[0].setMetadataValue("RANCH");

dto[1] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[1].setArticleId(11);
dto[1].setBaseId("SB11");
dto[1].setMetadataName("PRICE");
dto[1].setMetadataValue("1200000");

dto[2] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[2].setArticleId(11);
dto[2].setBaseId("SB11");
dto[2].setMetadataName("STATE");
dto[2].setMetadataValue("NJ");

dto[3] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[3].setArticleId(11);
dto[3].setBaseDocId("SB11");
dto[3].setMetadataName("REGION");
dto[3].setMetadataValue("NE");
//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
dto[4] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[4].setArticleId(12);
dto[4].setBaseId("SB12");
dto[4].setMetadataName("TYPE");
dto[4].setMetadataValue("RANCH");

dto[5] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[5].setArticleId(12);
dto[5].setBaseId("SB12");
dto[5].setMetadataName("PRICE");
dto[5].setMetadataValue("1200001");

dto[6] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[6].setArticleId(12);
dto[6].setBaseId("SB12");
dto[6].setMetadataName("STATE");
dto[6].setMetadataValue("NJ");

dto[7] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[7].setArticleId(12);
dto[7].setBaseId("SB12");
dto[7].setMetadataName("REGION");
dto[7].setMetadataValue("NE");

//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
dto[8] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[8].setArticleId(13);
dto[8].setBaseId("SB13");
dto[8].setMetadataName("TYPE");
dto[8].setMetadataValue("RANCH");

dto[9] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[9].setArticleId(13);
dto[9].setBaseId("SB13");
dto[9].setMetadataName("PRICE");
dto[9].setMetadataValue("1200002");

dto[10] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[10].setArticleId(13);
dto[10].setBaseId("SB13");
dto[10].setMetadataName("STATE");
dto[10].setMetadataValue("NJ");

dto[11] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[11].setArticleId(13);
dto[11].setBaseId("SB13");
dto[11].setMetadataName("REGION");
dto[11].setMetadataValue("NE");


//////////////////////////////////////////////////////
dto[12] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[12].setArticleId(14);
dto[12].setBaseId("SB14");
dto[12].setMetadataName("TYPE");
dto[12].setMetadataValue("RANCH");

dto[13] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[13].setArticleId(14);
dto[13].setBaseId("SB14");
dto[13].setMetadataName("PRICE");
dto[13].setMetadataValue("1200003");

dto[14] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[14].setArticleId(14);
dto[14].setBaseId("SB14");
dto[14].setMetadataName("STATE");
dto[14].setMetadataValue("NH");

dto[15] = new MetadatRetrievalDTO();
dto[15].setArticleId(14);
dto[15].setBaseId("SB14");
dto[15].setMetadataName("REGION");
dto[15].setMetadataValue("NE");
```

Where BaseIDs are unique per article. The search criterion is:

```
HashMap<String,String> queryParams = new HashMap<String, String>();
    queryParams.put("TYPE","RANCH");
    queryParams.put("STATE","NJ");
    queryParams.put("REGION","NE");
```

I wand to get all the DTOs which satisfy `queryParams`.
So the desired ArrayList should have all the records which match `queryParams`, so in my case it should exclude the last article with base Id = SB14 because in this article `State` is `NH`. How do I build a query that returns these results?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may need to rethink your data structures.  The way you have them currently setup, it will be rather difficult to create an efficient search.  If I understand what you are looking for the following code should get you the result you desire:

```
private Set filter(MetadatRetrievalDTO[] data, Map<String, String> filter) {
        Set<Integer> rtnIdSet = new HashSet();
        for (MetadatRetrievalDTO dto : data) {
            rtnIdSet.add(dto.getArticleId());
        }

        Set<Integer> filterSet = new HashSet();
        for (String key : filter.keySet()) {
            filterSet.clear();
            String value = filter.get(key);
            for (MetadatRetrievalDTO dto : data) {
                if (key.equals(dto.getMetadataName()) && value.equals(dto.getMetadataValue())) {
                    filterSet.add(dto.getArticleId());
                }
            }

            rtnIdSet.retainAll(filterSet);
        }

        return  rtnIdSet;
    }
```

Is this optimized? No.  Does it return an Array of the DTO's? No.  However, it does return a list of the article ids which match your filter criteria.  You can easily extend it to return a list of the dtos if you desire.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Kris , I know the data structure used are not optimum but this was legacy code and I'm making changes to suit some small requirements.

Answer (score 0):

```
for (MetadatRetrievalDTO dto : dtos) {
    for (Map.Entry entry : queryParams.entrySet()) {
        if (dto.getMetadataName().equals(entry.getKey()) && dto.getMetadataValue().equals(entry.getValue())) {
            // dto matches
        }
    } }
```

Not sure if this what you mean... But you should consider indexing or something like that...

Answer (score 0):

This is a terrible data structure. Something like a `Map<Long,Map<Field, String>>` would be much better, where `Long` is the articleId, `Field` is an enum of field names and `String` is the field value. For queries you can also maintain an inverse mapping of field/value pairs to ids.

Or, even better, do all this in an ORM/JPA framework and let a DBMS do all the hard work for you.